# Where is the auto-increment check box option in phpMyAdmin when creating a table?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, auto-increment

I've been working on my XAMPP local server and I've been just checking off the A_I column when creating a table for auto-increment. Now I'm trying to upload a website and on my godaddy's phpMyAdmin, I can't find the auto-increment button. I even tried the search function while on the page's source code, so I'm a bit confused now. How do I make a column auto-increment in the more recent versions of phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, it's under the 'extras' tab. Considering they only have the one option of 'auto-increment' under it, it boggles my mind why they would hide it under a tab and label it extras rather than just leaving it as a check mark, unless there are more options under 'extras' under different config.php settings for phpMyAdmin.